# add background image to entire screen, across all divs

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, background-image

I'm trying to get the following wordpress-based site to have a single continuous background image:

[Startup Roadmap | Idea Generation](http://theroadmap.co/generation/)

I can change background of individual elements but have not found a way to have a single background stretching across entire screen like [this](http://theroadmap.co/).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: show us code that you are using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this CSS to your body class

```
body.custom-background {
background: url('/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/assets/BG.jpg');
background-size: auto 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the background property of CSS, and then apply it to the parent html element that contains everything. For the website you stated it would be the "body" element.

Look into the different properties of background here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

here's an example I use over and over again:

```
/* Global Container */
.globalContainer {
width: 100%;
background: url(../PATHTOYOURPHOTO) no-repeat center bottom fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

You can look up the background-size property yourself, but "cover" generally scales the photo to fill the entire screen and not stretch. However based on the screen size some parts of the image may be left out.